# Flutter push notification not working in android release builds

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification

Push notification doesn't work on android release builds, but it works on debug builds. I have generated SHA-1 keys and added debug and release SHA-1 keys in the Firebase console.

Comment: you need to add new google-services.json file after adding release sh-1 to the console and try to check via rebuild

Comment: Yes, I did add new google-services.json file to my project

Comment: Is the package name the same for both debug and release versions?

Comment: yes, package names are the same for  both debug and release versions

Comment: I changed the firebase project, after adding SHA-1 to firebase and downloading the google-services.json, I had to run flutter clean. In this way, I solved the problem